# Not retrieving the character at an index of a list correctly?

Tags: global-variables, lisp, common-lisp

I am writing a program that recursively iterates through a list, provided the index of the current character and a list of characters. However, when I run the following program:

```
(defun printAllElementsRecursively (index providedList)
    (if (>= index (length providedList))
        (return-from printAllElementsRecursively NIL)
    )
    (defvar currCharacter (nth index providedList))
    (print (format nil "Character at index ~a: ~a" index currCharacter))
    (printAllElementsRecursively (+ index 1) providedList)
)

(printAllElementsRecursively 0 '(A B B A))
```

I get the following output:

```
"Character at index 0: A" 
"Character at index 1: A" 
"Character at index 2: A" 
"Character at index 3: A"
```

This seems strange, considering that the value of `index` does increment correctly.

Comment: Also, keep in mind Common Lisp is case insensitive, so a name like `printAllElementsRecursively` is going to be confusing. Generally, it's recommended that you use `snake-case` like all of the built-in functions do, but certainly something with mixed case is going to raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are misusing [`defvar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm):

1. It should *never* be used inside a function, use [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm) instead or just `(nth index providedList)` instead of `currCharacter`.
2. It *defines* a new global variable, and only sets it if it has *not* been set yet, so it sets
   `currCharacter` ***once*** only.

You also do not really need [`return-from`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_ret_fr.htm), and your code
would be more readable if use used dashes instead of camel case.
E.g.,

```
(defun print-list-elements-recursively (list)
   (when list
     (print (first list))
     (print-list-elements-recursively (rest list))))
```

Also, [`nth`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nth.htm) is ***linear*** in its *list* argument's length,
so your function is ***quadratic*** in it (my version is *linear*).